# Pagination redirects to home page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Hi I'm using pagenavi plugin, the problem is that when i click on page 2 or other pages in pagination, it redirects to my homepage, pagination is also working on home page,(a static front page). However, the wordpress pagination on archieve pages is working fine. Can anybody help me in this please...

```
<ul class="product-items">
    <?php
$paged = (get_query_var('pages')) ? get_query_var('pages') : 1;

 $args = array(
    'post_type'=>'product',
   'posts_per_page' => 12,
   'paged' => $paged
); 

$product_query = new WP_Query($args);

while($product_query->have_posts()):$product_query->the_post(); 
 $id = get_the_ID();

?>


        <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span class="product-img"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(300,150,true)) ?></span>
                <span class="product-detail"><?php $title=get_the_title(); echo $trimed=wp_trim_words($title,3) ?></span>
        </a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;   if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array('query' => $product_query)); }

wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query()?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand, on which page the pagination isn't working? The homepage or the archive page?

Comment: thanx mate for replaying...
pagination not working on home page... where i am using pagenavi.. also home page is not index.php it is  a static frontpage...

Comment: at archeive pages pagination working fine, default wordpress pagination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query var `pages` doesn't exists. You need to use `paged` instead:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

[See `get_query_var` documentation.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Getting_Current_Pagination_Number)

Comment: thanks for giving your time, I tried the solution but still the pagination is redirecting to homepage.

Comment: Same here, Please share the solution here if you got it  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function(){
    return 12; // posts per page to set in your case
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Increasing posts per page for woocommerce loop might solve this issue.